# Consultar en uso de un Servicio en C# con Defontana

Tags: c#, servicio

Donde trabajo tienen un programa (hecho en c#) que se conecta con DeFontana para generar facturas, este proyecto no es mio pero me pidieron analizarlo para sacar una información.

Bueno, tengo una ventana que en su botón **Facturar** tiene el siguiente código:

```
public FrmFacturaPorTipoDocumento(string tipoMovimiento = null, long? numeroDocumento = null, long? tipoDocumento = null)
{            
    InitializeComponent();
    CarregaInformacion();
    _ventaBusiness = new DocumentoVentaBusiness();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tipoMovimiento))
    {
        _tipoMovimiento = "";
    }
    else
    {
        _tipoMovimiento = tipoMovimiento;
        txtNumeroDocumentoOrigen.Text = numeroDocumento.ToString();
        cmbTipoDocumentoOrigen.SelectedValue = tipoDocumento;
        Facturar(_tipoMovimiento);
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, se entiende, la función Facturar tiene varias condiciones de las cuales voy a poner las que considero son las importantes:

Creo una variable *wsServidor* que llama al Servicio Facturación, se hace el primer *if* y dentro del *try* se llama al servicio y a la función **Facturar** que lleva datos, también lo entiendo

```
private void Facturar(string tipoMovimiento)
{
    var wsServidor = new FacturacionService.FacturacionClient();
    var informacionAdcional = new FacturacionService.InformacionAdicionalDataContract();            
    string vaRespuesta = "";
    txtRespuesta.Text = string.Empty;

    if (tipoMovimiento == "FAELECT") //factura
    {
        try
        {
            var retorno = wsServidor.Facturar(
                    txtNumeroDocumentoOrigen.Text.Trim(),
                    ((TipoDocumento)cmbTipoDocumentoOrigen.SelectedItem).Cod_Doc.ToString(),
                    "33",null
                    );

            ...
        }
        catch (SystemException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Error ao facturar!", Environment.NewLine,
                                        "Mensaje:", Environment.NewLine,
                                        ex.Message), "Facturación", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        txtRespuesta.Text = vaRespuesta;
    }
```

De este servicio yo puedo ver la referencia y sale que es algo autogenerado, voy a poner partes:

```
namespace Gestion4.FacturacionService {
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="InformacionAdicionalDataContract", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WsServidor.DataContract.Factura")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class InformacionAdicionalDataContract : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string CodigoTipoDocumentoField;

...
```

Leyendo veo que usa serialización, supongo que genera un xml de alguna forma y tiene otras variables aparte de la que se ve en la última línea.

Otra parte que es donde creo que manda a llamar es la siguiente dentro del mismo archivo:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="FacturacionService.IFacturacion")]
    public interface IFacturacion {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IFacturacion/Facturar", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IFacturacion/FacturarResponse")]
        Gestion4.FacturacionService.MessageDataContract Facturar(string numeroDocumento, string tipoDocumentoOrigen, string tipoDocumentoDestino, Gestion4.FacturacionService.InformacionAdicionalDataContract informacion);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IFacturacion/Facturar", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IFacturacion/FacturarResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Gestion4.FacturacionService.MessageDataContract> FacturarAsync(string numeroDocumento, string tipoDocumentoOrigen, string tipoDocumentoDestino, Gestion4.FacturacionService.InformacionAdicionalDataContract informacion);
```

Acá tengo dos Tasks, una de la **factura** que es la que recibe los datos enviados en el primer código que puse. Se que devuelve algo porque después me abre Internet Explorer con la Factura que se genera, pero mi consulta es. en base a esto que tengo. Yo puedo saber cómo envía o recibe la información dentro del visual studio? o tengo que definitivamente comunicarme con Defontana?

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar o guiar con esto.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podría ser una referencia a un servicio WCF? Si es así, lo más probable es que envíe y reciba una petición SOAP XML (Puedes confirmar el tipo de enlace en el fichero app.config). Podrías implementar IClientMessageInspector, lo que te permitiría inspeccionar el contenido de la llamada antes de enviar y después de recibir la respuesta.

Comment: Creo que si, revisé el archivo que me comentas y veo direcciones de este tipo: **\\172.16.21.34\Acepta\DTEService\custodium.com\dte-pruebas\var\ca4xml\output** y otra **http://172.16.111.15/wsServidor/Services/Facturacion.svc/facturacionoAddress** durante el día voy a tratar de implementar este Cliente que comentas y te respondo cómo me fue. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En el método facturar cambia

```
var wsServidor = new FacturacionService.FacturacionClient();
```

por

```
FacturacionService.FacturacionClient wsServidor = new FacturacionService.FacturacionClient();
```

Añade un behavior a wsServidor:

```
wsServidor .Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new DummyBehavior());
```

DummyBehaviour será una clase que implemente IEndpointBehavior:

```
 class DummyBehaviour : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        void IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IEndpointBehavior.Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

En el método ApplyClientBehavior, hay que añadir el inpector:

```
public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            DummyMessageInspector inspector = new DummyMessageInspector ();
            clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
        }
```

DummyMessageInspector será una clase que implemente IClientMessageInspector:

```
 class DummyInspector : System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector
    {
        void IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        object IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Ahora al realizar la llamada, podrás consultar el contenido del mensaje antes de salir, y al recibir la respuesta.

Saludos.